# Can I change Int.TryParse to return -1 instead of zero on an unsuccessful parsing?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, int, tryparse

Can I chagne `Int.TryParse` to return a custom number (like -1) instead of zero on an unsuccessful parsing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to do it is like this:

```
int myValue;
string myString = "Hi";

if( !int.TryParse( myString, out myValue)
{
  myValue = -1;
}
```

This will cause `myValue` to end up as -1, instead of 0.

Comment: Though this would result it myValue ending as -1 it doesn't answer the question. They're asking to change the method itself.

Comment: @Ash I assume that's just a misguided formulation. No sane person would want to change `TryParse` in such a way. That'd introduce so many bugs in code already building on `TryParse`.

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko - IMO this is the most vial option to obtain what he wants. He may have worded it as *change the method*, but I would bet that this is what he is *really* trying to accomplish. Tnx for downvote.

Comment: ... though, if someone posted an answer which shows how to literally change TryParse, I'd upvote it for the effort and LOLs.

Comment: @M.A. Hanin - Totally agreed :D

Comment: @MAH You can do it using the profiling API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188743.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `TryParse` to return -1. You can simply check if the parsing was unsuccessful and then assign -1 to your integer variable yourself.

```
int myInt;
if(!int.TryParse(s,out myInt))
  myInt=-1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the code of a framework method.  You could create a wrapper method, or an extension method instead.